# python issue: using `is` relational operator with `numpy.all()`

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, equality

When comparing [numpy.all()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) of a boolean array of `True` values using the `is` operator I get an unexpected `False` as output. However I get the expected outcome (`True`) when using the `==` operator. What is the likely reason for this comparison failure?

A sample code is attached below.

```py
In[2]: import sys
In[3]: print(sys.version)
3.9.5 

In[4]: import numpy as np
In[5]: np.__version__
'1.20.3'

In[6]: bool1 = True
In[7]: bool1 is True
True

In[8]: bool1 == True
True

In[9]: bool_arr = np.array([True, True, True, True])
In[10]: bool_arr.all()
True

In[11]: bool_arr.all() == True
True

In[12]: bool_arr.all() is True
False
```

As can be observed from the above code, in input 12, the expected outcome is `True` but the actual outcome is `False`.

I'm using pyenv in Ubuntu as the environment for python.

**EDIT:** as suggested in comments, this is not the best practice of using python. However, I'm interested to know the root cause for this failure.

Comment: The answer is, you don't.  The result of `np.all()` is already a Boolean value.  It is very bad practice to compare a Boolean value to `True` or `False`.

Comment: All you need is `bool_arr.all()`. No need to confirm that true is true.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion on best practice, but my question why does the comparison fail?

Comment: `is` compares the id of objects and they're not the same literal object try `print(id(True))` and `print(id(np.array([True]).all()))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the type of `bool_arr.all()`, the answer will be immediately apparent:

```
>>> bool_arr.all()
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

`np.all` returns an instance of a numpy `bool_`, which is a different class than python's built-in `bool` type. Instances of different types can not be the same object, which is what `is` is telling you.

The correct way to check truthiness is to let python wrap an expression in `bool` for you, e.g., in an `if` statement like `if bool_arr.all():`.

Comment: That makes sense. But why does `==` comparison work. Are they not comparing objects?

Comment: Why would `==` *not* work? It just calls `np.bool_.__eq__`. `True == 1` works fine too.